# Duplicate Value data in dropdown

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, duplicate

I have a basic requirement where in i am populating the textfield with people picker data and dynamically converting the textfield to dropdown.
Below is my code for value fetching.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" 
 type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){
var employeeName=$("input[title^='Employee Name']").val();
$("input[title^='Employee Name']").hide();
$("input[title^='Employee Name']").after("<select id='EmployeeField' class='ms-RadioText'><option value=''></option></select>");
var allEmployeeNames=getAllEmployeeNames();
$.each(allEmployeeNames,function(i,employee){
    if(employeeName==employee.Commercial_x0020_Lead.Title){
        $("#EmployeeField").append("<option selected='selected' value='"+employee.Commercial_x0020_Lead.Title+"'>"+employee.Commercial_x0020_Lead.Title+"</option>");
    }else{

            $("#EmployeeField").append("<option value='"+employee.Commercial_x0020_Lead.Title+"'>"+employee.Commercial_x0020_Lead.Title+"</option>");         
    }       
});
$("#EmployeeField").change(function(){
    $("input[title^='Employee Name']").val($(this).val());
});
  })
 function getAllEmployeeNames(){
var results;

$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists(guid'4BFF0A20-43A2-4444-881C-18932D468E54')/items?$select=Commercial_x0020_Lead/Title&$expand=Commercial_x0020_Lead/Id",
    type: "GET",
    async:false,
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: function (data) {
        if(data.d.results.length>0){
            results=data.d.results;

        }
    },
    error: function (data) {
        //alert("Error");
    }
});
return results;
  }
    </script>
```

But in my dropdown i get duplicate values as shown in image below:
[image]

Please help me solve this problem. 
Thanks

Comment: Hi ,I think yo need to clear the dropdown before start append  operation $("#EmployeeField").empty()

Comment: i am not trying to get you as to why clearing is required?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't obtain that you run the code on load. However, I don't have idea what happened with you.

Comment: Hi Jayant, whether the list from which you fetch "Commercial_x0020_Lead" column value has uniqueness enabled or not. if not then might be chance in your list you will have items with same "Commercial_x0020_Lead"  value in multiple place.if uniqueness is not enabled then using Javascript code you can bind only unique user to the drop down.this link might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25744763/get-distinct-data-of-sharepoint-list-using-rest-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the code below to achieve it.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var employeeName=$("input[title^='Employee Name']").val();
    $("input[title^='Employee Name']").hide();
    $("input[title^='Employee Name']").after("<select id='EmployeeField' class='ms-RadioText'><option value=''></option></select>");
    var allEmployeeNames=getAllEmployeeNames();
    $.each(allEmployeeNames,function(i,employee){
        if(employeeName==employee.Commercial_x0020_Lead.Title){
            $("#EmployeeField").append("<option selected='selected' value='"+employee.Commercial_x0020_Lead.Title+"'>"+employee.Commercial_x0020_Lead.Title+"</option>");
        }else{
            $("#EmployeeField").append("<option value='"+employee.Commercial_x0020_Lead.Title+"'>"+employee.Commercial_x0020_Lead.Title+"</option>");         
        }       
    });
    //remove duplicate values
    $("#EmployeeField option").each(function() {
        $(this).siblings('[value="'+ $(this).val() +'"]').remove();
    });
    $("#EmployeeField").change(function(){
        $("input[title^='Employee Name']").val($(this).val());
    });
})
function getAllEmployeeNames(){
    var results;

    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists(guid'4BFF0A20-43A2-4444-881C-18932D468E54')/items?$select=Commercial_x0020_Lead/Title&$expand=Commercial_x0020_Lead/Id",
        type: "GET",
        async:false,
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if(data.d.results.length>0){
                results=data.d.results;
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            //alert("Error");
        }
    });
    return results;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$("#fieldId").empty();
```